# ODBC/Linked Server Authentication/Authorization issue when running a stored procedure in code via .NET

Tags: sql-server, permissions, odbc, linked-server, dsn

I have a stored procedure that accesses a linked server set up on the local SQL Server instance. The linked server is configured to use a preconfigured ODBC DSN & driver. The connection works fine when directly executing the sp from SMSS on the server itself. I can query data and manipulate it as I need.

However, I have a program that I want to use to run and automate the stored procedure. I'm also running this program from the server instance. However when I attempt to run the stored procedure via code, I get the following message:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CARELOGIC" reported an error. Authentication failed.
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CARELOGIC".
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CARELOGIC" returned message "[Hortonworks][ThriftExtension] (8)
> Authentication/authorization error occurred. Error details: Bad Status: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized".

`Carelogic` is the name of the DSN/Linked Server. I'm not sure where the permissions break is. The authentication is done w/in the DSN itself and not in code. Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Linked servers have a security context too, specified with [sp_addlinkedserverlogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Perhaps that's not configured correctly, overriding the DSN security context configuration.

Comment: I added the sp_addlinkedserverlogin call to my stored procedure but it didn't seem to have an effect. I can still run in directly from the server box, but not in code or remotely.